# swift, moving SKSpriteNode?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to move a SpriteNode across the frame. I am currently having the issue of it having glitches while doing so (losing a couple of frames? not really sure). What I need is for the object to travel horizontally without a fixed direction x destination so that if x is offset by some impact the object does not attempt to return to its initialized x coordinate.
Here is how that part of the code looks like right now:

```
`spaceRock.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
spaceRock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: (spaceRock?.texture)!, 
size:(spaceRock.size))
spaceRock.zPosition = 1
spaceRock.position=CGPoint(x: xSpawnPosition, y: 
Double(self.size.height/2+(spaceRock.size.height)))
spaceRock.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
spaceRock.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true
spaceRock.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 00000001
spaceRock.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 00000010
addChild(spaceRock)
spaceRock.physicsBody?.applyTorque(CGFloat(randTorque))
//spaceRock.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: -self.size.height-
spaceRock.size.height, duration: rockTravelTime))`
```

The comment is what I have been using up until this point.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing physics simulation (SKPhysicsBody) and direct movement of the Sprite (SKAction.moveTo) - although you may be able to do that to achieve special effects, in general they will fight each other and cause problems.

If you need your objects to move realistically, then use an SKPhysicsBody and apply forces (Torque, thrust etc.) to move it. This will be quite complex to program and has a significant processing overhead.

If you prefer to move your sprites directly then get rid of the SKPhysicsBody and your moveTo should then work fine.

Comment: Say I took SKPhysicsBody out, how would I test for contact between two nodes?

Comment: @Ari You could check to see if their frames overlap using SKNode's intersects method. It depends on what you want to achieve. Physics might be the best way to go, but then you should use physics to move your bodies too.